# Debug VB 6.0 ActiveX DLL with .pdb file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb6, com-interop, pdb-files

I have a VB 6.0 Project that I am able to compile and build the ActiveX DLL and .pdb file.

I have added the .dll as a COM reference to my C# project in Visual Studio 2019 and it works fine.

The problem is that I can't step into ActiveX DLL during debugging in Visual Studio and the .pdb file is not been loaded.

Can Visual Studio work with .pdb files of VB 6.0?
Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach to the ActiveX container (IE most likely).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-an-activex-control?view=vs-2019